# angularjs ng-repeat using index rather than names

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I use ng-repat to populate an html table with an array.

I have problems normalizing the naming of each property in the array.

Some users are very stubborn and now I have to find a quick work around, if possible.

my array AgendaItems sometimes comes like:

```
{"Agenda Item":"1","Legistar ID":"62236","Title":"Approval of Minutes","Meeting ID":"49837"}
```

Other times comes like:

```
{"AgendaItem":"1","LegistarID":"62236","Title":"Approval of Minutes","MeetingID":"49837"}
```

The html:

```
                    <tbody ng-repeat="ai in AgendaItems">   
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ai.MeetingID}}</td>
                            <td>{{ai.AgendaItem}}</td>
                            <td>{{ai.LegistarID}}</td>
                            <td>{{ai.Title}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Is there a way that I can use an index value instead that, for example: ai.[i]
That way I do not have to worry whether the columns are name with or without a space in between?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you,
Erasmo

Comment: @Dalorzo - do I also change the ai in AgendaItems? would you mind showing me the complete example? Thank you

Comment: If you are AgendaItems has spaces it will not be a valid json object, therefore it should be a problem not for angular but for you JS project

Comment: You have implicit access in [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to scoped variables like `$index`. However, using `$index` when iterating over an _object_ rather than an array is rather questionable.

Comment: Did you try to iterate over "ai" properties like <td ng-repeat="(name, value) in ai">{{value}}</td> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implicit access in [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to scope properties like `$index` which the directive provides automatically.

However, using `$index` when iterating over an *object* rather than an array is rather questionable.

What you seem to be after is rather a way to iterate over an object's keys and values, which is not questionable and is in fact also supported by `ng-repeat` via the `"(key, value) in object"` syntax. *The names `key` and `value` are arbitrary.*

Here's how that would be written:

Firstly, for a single `agendaItem`, `ai`

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in ai">{{key}}: {{value}}</div>
</div>
```

Secondly, in the question's context

```
<tbody ng-repeat="ai in AgendaItems">
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in ai">{{value}}</td>
  </tr>
</tody>
```